# When I drag an image that has been rotated with css, it will drag in a non-rotated manner(original)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, css

I was making a CSS grid to display images, the images are rotated 60 degrees to make a diagonal viewing. The problem is I want users to be able to drag and drop images around in the grid to move the images, but when they drag the image it drags as if it wasn't rotated at all. note: I am not using a canvas element, I am using a pure  element.

I have tried looking into method of solving this problem with one of the following: jQuery, Javascript, React JS, CSS but haven't found any solutions that are clean/or even work. I thought about just re-capturing all of the images in their rotated state, but this would take forever with the amount of images I am dealing with.

I rotate the image via css

```css
    behavior:url(-ms-transform.htc);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform:rotate(315deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform:rotate(315deg);
    /* IE9 */
    -ms-transform:rotate(315deg);
    /* IE6,IE7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476);
    /* IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
```

I just want to be able to have the users drag the image, and have it keep the rotation it has in place when dragging. Any helps is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could draw them, rotated, onto canvases and move those around. Could also wrap each in an SVG and drag that around.

Comment: @Ouroborus that is an okay idea, if all else fails I will probably end up doing that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you please add your drag and drop code.

Comment: @SamyakJain I do not have a drag and drop code, as I wasn't able to successfully come up with anything that remotely worked. I am just dragging the image via the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle through javascripts -

overwrite on browser's drag event. this will let your rotation css remain there.

```
ball.ondragstart = function() {
                return false;
                };
```

Full drag and drop code with -

```
<img src="./samyak/images/0.jpeg" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; z-index: 1000; left: 777px; top: 39px; transition: auto 0s ease 0s;" width="40" height="40" id="ball">
<script>
            ball = document.getElementById("ball");
            ball.style.transform="rotate(30deg)"
            ball.ondragstart = function() {
            return false;
            };
            ball.onmousedown = function(event) { // (1) start the process

            // (2) prepare to moving: make absolute and on top by z-index
            ball.style.position = 'absolute';
            ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
            // move it out of any current parents directly into body
            // to make it positioned relative to the body
            document.body.append(ball);
            // ...and put that absolutely positioned ball under the cursor

            moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

            // centers the ball at (pageX, pageY) coordinates
            function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
            ball.style.left = pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
            ball.style.top = pageY - ball.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            }

            function onMouseMove(event) {
            moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            }

            // (3) move the ball on mousemove
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

            // (4) drop the ball, remove unneeded handlers
            ball.onmouseup = function() {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            ball.onmouseup = null;
            };

        }
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't quite do what I wanted, but with a little editing it works perfectly for my project. I answers the question completely so this answer is correct.